# Find the value of $c$ where $c$ is constant?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> **Question.** Find the constant $c$ such that the following problem has a solution 
>   $$-u''=c ~\text{in}~(a,b)\\
> u'(a)=-1,~u'(b)=1$$

**My try:** if the second derivative of $u$ is a constant $c$ then we can guess $u$ is a polynomial of second degree of the form $u = dx^2 + ex + f$. Taking the derivatives we get:

$$-u'' = -2d = c \iff d = -\frac{c}{2}\tag{1}\\u' = 2dx + e$$

Now  $u'(a)= - a c + e= -1 \tag 1$

$ u'(b)= - bc + e= 1 \tag2$

after solving $1$ and $2$   i got  $c=\frac{2e}{a+b}$

Is my answer is true/false

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine, except the last step. What is $e$ or even better: Why don't you express the solution for $c$ without using an unknown $e$? Hint: Subtract (1) from (2).

Comment: if we substract it will give  $-1-1=0 $ no  solution exist

Comment: so  we must add the two boundary equation

Comment: No, subtract, since you want to get rid of $e$. $1-(-1)=2$ shouldn't be an issue.